# WHERE clause with relationship to another table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've got a couple of tables in my Laravel application, one called shipments and the other called payments_distributions.

In my shipments, I have columns called pro_number and balance.

In my payments_distributions I have columns called shipment_id and amount.

Now I have a controller which has this portion of code in it:

```
}elseif($_GET['paymentStatus']=="Unpaid"){
    if(empty($_GET['pro_number'])){
            $shipment = NULL;
        }else{
        $shipment = $_GET['pro_number'];
        }

        if($_GET['startDate']){
            $startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
        }
        if($_GET['endDate']){
            $endDate = $_GET['endDate'];
        }
                $start = $_GET['startDate'];
                $end = $_GET['endDate'];
                $status = $_GET['paymentStatus'];
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(0);

    $shipments = Shipment::sortable()
    ->where([
        ['due_date','<=',date($date)],
        ['pro_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $shipment . '%'],
        ['balance','>','SELECT SUM(payments_distributions.amount) FROM payments_distributions WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number'],
    ])
    ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->whereNotIn('shipment_billing_status', [2,3])
    ->paginate(25);
    return view('shipments.accounts', compact('shipments','start','end','status'));

}
```

Now my issue arises in that the following code works if I put it into MYSQL:

```
SELECT SUM(payments_distributions.amount) FROM payments_distributions WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = 214050
```

Will return SUM(payments_distributions.amount): 300.00

So, if you go to the line in my code, this is the only thing that doesn't work, so if you could, does this line of code look right to everyone? All I'm trying to say that the balance field from a shipment row must be larger than the sum of amount fields in the payment_distributions table where the shipment_id field in the payment_distributions table equals the pro_number field in the shipments table.

```
 ['balance','>','SELECT SUM(payments_distributions.amount) FROM payments_distributions WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number'],
    ]
```

### Update (the entire function)

```
public function accountsQuery(){


if(($_GET['paymentStatus'] == "No Settle") or ($_GET['paymentStatus'] == "No Charge")){
            if($_GET['paymentStatus'] == "No Settle"){
                $status = 3;
            }elseif($_GET['paymentStatus'] == "No Charge"){
                $status = 2;
            }
                if(empty($_GET['pro_number'])){
                $shipment = NULL;
                }else{
                $shipment = $_GET['pro_number'];
                }

                if($_GET['startDate']){
                    $startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
                }
                if($_GET['endDate']){
                    $endDate = $_GET['endDate'];
                }
                        $start = $_GET['startDate'];
                        $end = $_GET['endDate'];
                        $status = $_GET['paymentStatus'];
                        $shipments = \App\Shipment::sortable()->where([ 
                            ['pro_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $shipment . '%'],
                            ['shipment_billing_status', 'LIKE', '%' . $status . '%'],
                        ])
                            ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                            ->paginate(25);
                return view('shipments.accounts', compact('shipments','start','end','status'));

}elseif($_GET['paymentStatus']=="Billed"){
    if(empty($_GET['pro_number'])){
            $shipment = NULL;
        }else{
        $shipment = $_GET['pro_number'];
        }

        if($_GET['startDate']){
            $startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
        }
        if($_GET['endDate']){
            $endDate = $_GET['endDate'];
        }
                $start = $_GET['startDate'];
                $end = $_GET['endDate'];
                $status = $_GET['paymentStatus'];
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(30);
    //AND TO MENTION WHERE SUM OF PAYMENTS TO THIS SHIPMENT < BALANCE DUE
    $shipments = Shipment::sortable()
    ->where([
        ['date','>=', date($date)],
        ['pro_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $shipment . '%'],
    ])
    ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->paginate(25);
    return view('shipments.accounts', compact('shipments','start','end','status'));

}elseif($_GET['paymentStatus']=="Unpaid"){
    if(empty($_GET['pro_number'])){
            $shipment = NULL;
        }else{
        $shipment = $_GET['pro_number'];
        }

        if($_GET['startDate']){
            $startDate = $_GET['startDate'];
        }
        if($_GET['endDate']){
            $endDate = $_GET['endDate'];
        }
                $start = $_GET['startDate'];
                $end = $_GET['endDate'];
                $status = $_GET['paymentStatus'];
    $date = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(0);

    $shipments = Shipment::sortable()
    ->where([
        ['due_date','<=',date($date)],
        ['pro_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $shipment . '%'],
    ])
    ->whereRaw('balance > SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id = pro_number')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
    ->whereNotIn('shipment_billing_status', [2,3])
    ->paginate(25);
    return view('shipments.accounts', compact('shipments','start','end','status'));

}  
}
```

Comment: Try surrounding the inner SELECT (where you compare to balance) with a DB::raw() call. The issue you are seeing is because the query builder is comparing balance with a string containing the SQL statement, not the results of the SQL statement.

Comment: @Jason - I have changed everything back to the original and now in my where([.... portion I have the following: ['balance', '>', DB::raw('SELECT IFNULL(SUM(p.amount),0) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id = shipments.pro_number')], - but I am returned with this error

Comment: have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT IFNULL(SUM(p.amount),0) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `shipments` where (`due_date` <= 2017-12-26 00:00:00 and `pro_number` LIKE %% and `balance` > SELECT IFNULL(SUM(p.amount),0) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id = shipments.pro_number) and `date` between 1997-12-01 and 2017-12-26 and `shipment_billing_status` not in (2, 3))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use that subquery as part of a `whereRaw` expression:

```
->where([
    ['due_date','<=',date($date)],
    ['pro_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $shipment . '%']])
->whereRaw('balance > SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id = pro_number')
->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
...
```

However, I suspect that we can probably rewrite your query to do away with this correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id = pro_num' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `shipments` where (`due_date` <= 2017-12-26 00:00:00 and `pro_number` LIKE %%) and balance > SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM payments_distributions p WHERE p.shipment_id = pro_number and `date` between 1997-12-01 and 2017-12-25 and `shipment_billing_status` not in (2, 3))

Comment: And I am using the whereRaw you suggested, I know you must be close, is there something you might have to suggest for me to try and work out? I'll keep trying things and let you know if I can find something. Thanks again - Matt

Comment: @Matthew The error output appears to be from a query slightly different than what is in your question.  Can you edit your question with the actual query you are running?  From what I have read, my use of `whereRaw` is legitimate.

Comment: actually for the section that is being referred to, they are the same queries. I can post the entire function but at the moment all I am sending through is that "paymentStatus" = "Unpaid". I'll post the whole function,

Comment: Better yet, maybe post the raw MySQL query.  I think we can phrase it in such a way that we don't need `whereRaw`.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion where I would pull that given that I am handling this all through Laravel? Sorry, been working on this project too long haha.

Comment: @Matthew The only thing I can suggest is to pare down the problem to something minimal.  That `whereRaw` is not working might imply the query has other problems.  Or, you can wait for a Laravel guru to give a better answer than mine.